# Can the prohibition on drinking from the mouth of the waterskin be applied to drinking from the mouth of the bottle?

Tags: hadith, fiqh, hadith-interpretation

Narrated Abu Huraira:

The Prophet (ﷺ) forbade the drinking of water directly from the mouth of a water skin .

> Narrated Abu Huraira:
>
> The Prophet (ﷺ) forbade the drinking of water directly from the mouth
>   of a water skin .
>   
>  **Source**: https://sunnah.com/bukhari/74/54

Note:
Water skin is the vessel in which water is put and it has a mouth from which it is drunk.

Comment: Is it a coincidence that your question and note is exactly the same question and information in https://islamqa.info/en/112010?